# Does OpenSSL offer Big Decimal support?

Tags: c, openssl

I've used OpenSSL *BIGNUM* to implement some cryptosystems and I am now wondering if it also offers big decimal support. I could not find anything in the documentation but perhaps there is an extension/add-on somewhere preferably in C (not C++)?

Note: I am aware of GMP and NTL, I am not looking for those.

Comment: I seem to recall Knuth offers the algorithms for Big Decimals given Big Integers. See Knuth's [The Art of Computer Programming (AOCP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming). I would look in Volume II first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does OpenSSL offer Big Decimal support?

No.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know OpenSSL uses BigNumber library to implement operation on large numbers, ant this is recommended way to follow for devs.
More info: http://linux.die.net/man/3/bn_print